# "Edit tags" link disappears

Tags: bug, inline-tag-editor

Sometimes the "Edit tags" link below a question disappears. Refreshing the page restores it.

I'm not sure, but I think it mostly happens after I've edited the question.

If relevant, I've only noticed this in Stack Overflow, but that's the only site where I have enough rep to use the inline tag editor.

Comment: Yes, that has been the case for the past few weeks.